# How to find unused IAM roles(for ec2,lambda) in AWS by using python code,I didn't find any boto calls for unused iam roles

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-iam

I want to extract all IAM roles (with and without instance-profiles) which have not been used for more than 90 days.

Comment: Can you get the same info from AWS console/dashboard?

Comment: we can get it from console... but if we have large env .. then it's not possible to goto console to check for every role. @helloV